# DbContext with IQueryable entities write custom queries

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, entity-framework-5

I am stuck with this requirement for the past of couple days without much progress.

Our database layer is handled through DbContext with repository , unit of work pattern.
It works on the poko classes to generate queries.

```
public virtual IQueryable<ENT> All(params Expression<Func<ENT, object>>[] includes)
    {
        IQueryable<ENT> query = Set;

        query = AddIncludesToQry(query, includes);

        return query;
    }

protected DbSet<ENT> Set
    {
        get { return Ctxt.Set<ENT>(); }
    }

protected virtual IQueryable<ENT> AddIncludesToQry(IQueryable<ENT> query, params Expression<Func<ENT, object>>[] includes)
    {
        Expression<Func<ENT, object>>[] includesToUse = d2l.NullOrEmpty(includes)
            ? DefaultIncludes
            : includes;

        if (d2l.NullOrEmpty(includesToUse)) return query;

        foreach (var incl in includesToUse)
        {
            query = query.Include(incl);
        }

        return query;
    }
```

ENT = poko model class

AddIncludesToQry = Adds the condition in where clause.

This will return the entire table data (there will be a table with poko class name in database) by filtering the where conditions.

However, I want get the data sometimes little differently.
For ex, I want to restrict select list to return deptName, Count(employee)
This requires just two columns in select list, and group by deptName.

I am not sure how I can achieve this using this pattern that can still be IQueryable query.

can somebody advise any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

After a grouping operation, the schema of the data you're working on changes (exactly as in plain SQL). So you surely can continue to reference your query as an `IQueryable`, BUT NOT as `IQueryable<ENT>` (as I suspect you would like to).

In the case IQueryable it's enough:

```
newQry = qry
    .GroupBy(x => x.deptName)
    .Select(y => new { deptName = y.Key, count = y.Count() });
```